# ORACLE Recursive query

Tags: oracle, recursive-query

I'm trying to build a recursive query and I'm facing a problem.

please find below my dataset

```
WITH table1 ( ID, Code, Label ) as(
  SELECT 123, 'C1', 'LABEL_1' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'C2', 'LABEL_2' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 'C3', 'LABEL_3' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 44, 'C4', 'LABEL_4' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'C5', 'LABEL_5' from dual
),
table2 ( ID, id_table1, code_child, label_child ) as (
  SELECT 1,  123, 'C1_1','LABEL_1_1' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,  123, 'C1_2','LABEL_1_2' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,  123, 'C1_3','LABEL_1_3' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,  123, 'C1_4','LABEL_1_4' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 6,  30, 'C3_1','LABEL_3_1' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 7,  30, 'C3_2','LABEL_3_2' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 8,  30, 'C3_3','LABEL_3_3' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 9,  30, 'C3_4','LABEL_3_4' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 5, 'C5_1','LABEL_5_1' from dual
),
hierarchy as (
Select
    a.id, code, label, CODE_CHILD,id_table1
from table1     a
    left join table2 b on b.id_table1 = a.ID
    )
,recursive (base, id, code, label, CODE_CHILD,id_table1) as (
    SELECT
       id as base,
       id, 
       code, 
       label, 
       CODE_CHILD,
       id_table1
    FROM hierarchy 
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        previous_level.base,
        current_level.id,
        current_level.code, 
       current_level.label, 
       current_level.CODE_CHILD,
       current_level.id_table1
    FROM  recursive previous_level,
          hierarchy current_level
    WHERE  1=1 
            and current_level.id = previous_level.id_table1
    )
SELECT * FROM recursive order by   base;
```

And i'm getting this error :
32044. 00000 -  "cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query"
*Cause:    A recursive WITH clause query produced a cycle and was stopped
           in order to avoid an infinite loop.
*Action:   Rewrite the recursive WITH query to stop the recursion or use
           the CYCLE clause.

Where i'm wrong ?

**I need to merge these two tables into one.**
here's what I'd like to get as a result.

```
id  code    label      id_parent
1   C1      LABEL_1 
2   C2      LABEL_2 
3   C3      LABEL_3 
4   C4      LABEL_4 
5   C5      LABEL_5 
6   C1_1    LABEL_1_1   1
7   C1_2    LABEL_1_2   1
8   C1_3    LABEL_1_3   1
9   C1_4    LABEL_1_4   1
10  C3_1    LABEL_3_1   3
11  C3_2    LABEL_3_2   3
12  C3_3    LABEL_3_3   3
13  C3_4    LABEL_3_4   3
14  C5_1    LABEL_5_1   5
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want a recursive query? It appears that you could just use `UNION ALL` and join the two tables:

```sql
WITH table1 ( ID, Code, Label ) as(
  SELECT 1, 'C1', 'LABEL_1' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'C2', 'LABEL_2' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'C3', 'LABEL_3' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'C4', 'LABEL_4' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'C5', 'LABEL_5' from dual
),
table2 ( ID, id_table1, code_child, label_child ) as (
  SELECT 1,  1, 'C1_1','LABEL_1_1' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,  1, 'C1_2','LABEL_1_2' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,  1, 'C1_3','LABEL_1_3' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,  1, 'C1_4','LABEL_1_4' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 6,  3, 'C3_1','LABEL_3_1' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 7,  3, 'C3_2','LABEL_3_2' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 8,  3, 'C3_3','LABEL_3_3' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 9,  3, 'C3_4','LABEL_3_4' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 5, 'C5_1','LABEL_5_1' from dual
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY table_no, code ) AS id,
       code,
       label,
       id_parent
FROM   (
  SELECT code,
         label,
         1 AS table_no,
         NULL AS id_parent
  FROM   table1
UNION ALL
  SELECT code_child,
         label_child,
         2 AS table_no,
         id_table1
  FROM   table2
)
order by table_no, code;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ID | CODE | LABEL     | ID_PARENT
> -: | :--- | :-------- | --------:
>  1 | C1   | LABEL_1   |      null
>  2 | C2   | LABEL_2   |      null
>  3 | C3   | LABEL_3   |      null
>  4 | C4   | LABEL_4   |      null
>  5 | C5   | LABEL_5   |      null
>  6 | C1_1 | LABEL_1_1 |         1
>  7 | C1_2 | LABEL_1_2 |         1
>  8 | C1_3 | LABEL_1_3 |         1
>  9 | C1_4 | LABEL_1_4 |         1
> 10 | C3_1 | LABEL_3_1 |         3
> 11 | C3_2 | LABEL_3_2 |         3
> 12 | C3_3 | LABEL_3_3 |         3
> 13 | C3_4 | LABEL_3_4 |         3
> 14 | C5_1 | LABEL_5_1 |         5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca324c454ac324b2807147008d6af698)*

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it's not working as expected. The IDs in my table 1 are not, in my db, as I wrote in my example.
I edited my post
I thought, wrongly, that when there was a father-son relationship it implied a recursive request
thank you

Answer (score 0):

A recursive WITH clause query produced a cycle and was stopped in order to avoid an infinite loop.

This issue is coming due to bad data in the DB. There are some records which are causing circular relationship among them which is causing infinite loops.

For example: P is parent of C and C is again parent of P.

You can fetch the above output simple using UNION ALL and join of the tables.